# Quit is grayed out in Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app

My Mail has the *Quit* menu item disabled, and it doesn't allow me to quit it.

[image: screenshot]

I know that similar question has been asked here before, but it doesn't have any positive answer.

It happens very sporadic so I cannot understand what causes it.

[image]

The only way to quit Mail is to force-quit it in Activity monitor. After that mail works normally.

[image]

What I remember from day before is that I did try to move a group of mail to another folder using the rules and that got stuck.

Looking in the Console I find this as most recent mail activity. There is a huge report attached to it, so I won't publish it here unless requested.

> 8/1/13 9:16:44.356 AM sandboxd[6335]: ([6153]) Mail(6153) deny file-issue-extension

Also looking in the Console from day before here is what Mail reported.

[image: screenshot]

MBA with OS 10.8.4 and Mail 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that is because the Mail was sill busy.

I had mail settings to do "stuff" on mail quit.

[image: mail]

Using the Activity window I saw it was active, and that is the reason it would not allow me to Quit instantly.

<sub>Doing the Force quit is not a good idea for this.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One of two things has happened to make Mail non-responsive during the normal quit process.

1. The entire program has hung (and you will see it as non-responsive in Activity Monitor or the Force Quit dialog window).
2. Mail's background threads for interacting with mail servers have hung and not timed out (and you can open the Activity Window from Mail's Window Menu) to see what specific account and perhaps even what it's trying to do (such as delete messages, send mail, update or synchronize a folder, etc…)

Once the quit menu is dim - you can either force quit the app, wait for it ti finish quitting or log out of that user (perhaps by rebooting) but you can be sure the Mail program is trying to quit at this point so you can continue to use it or decide to help it down as you see fit.